# Kafka python consumer not reading the message from topics

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I was trying to read the message available in specified topic as shown below:

```
def consumer():
    consumer = KafkaConsumer('TOPIC_NAME',
                             enable_auto_commit=False,
                             value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii')),
                             bootstrap_servers=['xx.x.xx.xx:port'],
                             auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                             api_version=(20, 2, 1),
                             consumer_timeout_ms=1000
                             )

    #consumer.subscribe(['TOPIC_NAME'])
    for _ in range(10):
        msg = consumer.poll(0.05)
        if msg:
            dat = {
                'msg_value': msg.value(),  # This is the actual content of the message
                'msg_headers': msg.headers(),  # Headers of the message
                'msg_key': msg.key(),  # Message Key
                'msg_partition': msg.partition(),  # Partition id from which the message was extracted
                'msg_topic': msg.topic(),  # Topic in which Producer posted the message to
            }
            print(dat)
        print('No Msg found')
```

Am not getting any error , but its not reading any message, just printing **No Msg Found**. When I checked on the topic, messages are there. Can anyone please help me to know if i have missed anything here.

Comment: You should put name of the topic here `consumer.subscribe(['TOPIC_NAME'])` or you can remove this line as you have already included topic to be subscribed as parameter while defining consumer.

Comment: @zweack still the same problem

Comment: Have you tried specifying a group id? Then describing that group to make sure the consumer is actually processing data?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your reply.  Tried already, still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried a different client, such as the one from confluent?

Answer (score 0):

For Kafka consumer, I believe a more standard implementation is:

```
for message in consumer:
    print(msg)
```

If you insist on using consumer.poll(), please **do not set time_out to a number as small as 0.05**, and **use while true to continuously poll**.